# Parse text files using Python

Tags: python

I have a log file that I would like to parse and plot using matplotlib. After skipping the first 6 lines, I have data of interest.
e.g. my log file looks like this:

```
# 2014-05-09 17:51:50,473 - root - INFO - Epoch = 1, batch = 216, Classif Err = 52.926, lg(p) -1.0350
# 2014-05-09 17:51:53,749 - root - INFO - Test set error = 37.2317
```

I want to make a plot of the Classif Err vs Test set error for each Epoch.

My first attempt at this:

```
import numpy
from numpy import *
from pylab import *

f1 = open('log.txt', 'r')
FILE = f1.readlines()
f1.close()

for line in FILE:
    line = line.strip()
    if ('Epoch' in line):
        epoch += line.split('Epoch = ')
    elif('Test set error' in line):
        test_err += line.split('Test set error = ')
```

I see this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "logfileparse.py", line 18, in <module>
    epoch += line.split('Epoch = ')
NameError: name 'epoch' is not defined
```

Comment: Read the error carefully "epoch" undefined. to concatenate epoch, first epoch should be initialized. like epoch = [] or "" or anything you want

Comment: Why you are not using line.spli(' ') to create a list of all words then grab your interest parts using list indexing?

Comment: @Shahinism ok. I see ` '2014-05-09',
 '18:35:59,131',
 '-',
 'root',
 '-',
 'INFO',
 '-',
 'Test',
 'set',
 'error',
 '=',
 '16.0433'` which are different values.

Comment: Sorry about my bad suggestion! as @iamsudip said your problem here is that you are not defined the variable epoch in your code! you can define it as a string just before your for loop like `epoch=""` and I think every think will work just fine.

Comment: I would use regex for this types of parsing

Comment: what exact output do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to get a set of epoch and the test set errors together to plot them. Assuming the error line is always after the line with 'epoch', try this:

```
data_points = []
ep = 'Epoch = (\d+), batch = \d+, Classif Err = (\d+\.?\d+)'

with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
       epoch = re.findall(ep, line)
       if epoch:
           error_line = next(f) # grab the next line, which is the error line
           error_value = error_line[error_line.rfind('=')+1:]
           data_points.append(map(float,epoch[0]+(error_value,)))
```

Now `data_points` will be a list of lists, the first value is the epoch, the second the classif err value, and the third the error value.

The regular expression will return a list with a tuple:

```
>>> re.findall(ep, i)
[('1', '52.926')]
```

*Here `i` is your first line*

To grab the error code, find the last `=` and then the error code is the remaining characters:

```
>>> i2 = '# 2014-05-09 17:51:53,749 - root - INFO - Test set error = 37.2317'
>>> i2[i2.rfind('=')+1:]
' 37.2317'
```

I used `map(float,epoch[0]+(error_value,))` to convert the values from strings to floats:

```
>>> map(float, re.findall(ep, i)[0]+(i2[i2.rfind('=')+1:],))
[1.0, 52.926, 37.2317]
```

Comment: thanks for this tip. I was able to plot the values like this: `epochs = [x[0] for x in data_points]
cerr = [x[1] for x in data_points]
terr = [x[2] for x in data_points]

plot(epochs, cerr, label='class_err')
plot(epochs, terr, label='test_err')
xlabel('epochs')
ylabel('error')
title('Classification Error and Test Error')
pylab.legend(loc='upper right')
grid(True)
show()`

Answer (score 1):

This will find Epoch and its value, appending it to a list.

```
epoch=[] # define epoch
with open('log.txt', 'r') as f: #  use with to open files as it automatically closes the file
    for line in f:
        if "Epoch" in line:
            epoch.append(line[line.find("Epoch ="):].split(',')[0])
        elif('Test set error' in line):
            test_error.append(line[line.find("Test set error ="):].split(',')[0]) 
print epoch
['Epoch = 1']
print test_error
['Test set error = 37.2317']
```

Uses index of "Epoch" to slice the string, split on ',' and append first element "Epoch = ..."
to the epoch list.

Answer (score 1):

As I tried your code more, I saw there is another problem after you didn't defined `epoch` variable. And by that I mean you are trying to concatenate a `list` object to a `string` object as your code shows to us! I tried to validate this code and got something like this:

```
epoch = []
for line in f1.readlines():
    line_list = line.split(' ')
    if 'Epoch' in line_list:
        epoch_index = line_list.index('Epoch')
        message = ' '.join(line_list[epoch_index:])
        epoch.append(message)
    elif 'Test set error' in line_list:
        error_index = line_list.index('Test set error')
        message = ' '.join(line_list[error_index:])
        epoch.append(message)
```

Comment: might pay to actually explain what your code is doing and

Comment: Here I just want to extract some keywords and append the string after that as a list argument to the `epoch` list! It is just what I found in the question explanation. But I think there is enough code here to answer the actual question :D

Answer (score 0):

You do not initialize the variable epoch.
is important that you do before:

> epoch += line.split('Epoch = ')